# MySQL Column Value Breaking HTML Syntax In OnClick

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue where a PHP variable's value from a MySQL database is breaking my HTML syntax.

```
<?php
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openContentWindow(\''.$row['creativeStrengths'].'\')">Open content</a>';
?>
```

If the string contains a `"` or `'` it will break my string and give an error.

Is there any way to escape the characters in HTML? Or if there is a way to use javascript/jquery in this situation that's fine too.

The value of $row['creativeStrengths'] is a string by the way hence the single quotes around it.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I solved my issue by using addslashes(). Sorry that my question may not have been specific enough. Your answers were most likely right however I may not have clarified enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using addslashes().

`addslashes($row['creativeStrengths']);`

Answer (score 0):

The escape code for `"` is `&#34;` and the escape code for `'` is `&#39;`. The entity name for the former is `&quot;`, but I don't know if there is one for the latter.

[Source](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

Comment: Hmm, the issue with my code though is that I have no idea where there could be a `'` or `"` in the string.

Comment: @Nicolas In that case I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. The string outputs HTML which breaks your PHP code, because the outputted HTML is not escaped?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I do not know where a `'` or `"` character may be in the string because the values are user set by a form which is then inserted into the database. Therefore I don't know where to put the escape codes.

Comment: In that case, you can scroll down and answer your own question with the information you've found, and then mark it as accepted. That way it is posted in clear, proper format for anyone who comes across this question in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
htmlspecialchars($row['creativeStrengths'])
```

It will escape any HTML character.

Comment: `echo '<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openContentWindow(\''.htmlspecialchars($row['creativeStrengths']).'\')">Open content</a>';` Didn't seem to work.